# How to conditionally render label to avoid labels overlapping in recharts?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, recharts

I'm having an issue similar to [this](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/490) using **Recharts** library with NextJS.

I'm using a `ComposedChart` that renders `Bar` and `Line` components.

However, the `Label`s are overlapping on each other if the value is not big enough between them.

[image: Bar chart]

Is there any way we can conditionally render out the `Label` inside `LabelList` if the data's value is higher than a specific value? (Ex: Hide the `Label` when the data's value is lower than `5`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [formatter](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/LabelList#formatter) property to control the content that gets displayed and simply return `null` if you want to hide your label:

```
<LabelList
    dataKey={yourKey}
    fill={fill}
    position="top"
    formatter={label => {                                              
        return label > 5 ? label : null;
    }}
/>
```